# Odata get counts in select query (V3)

Tags: objective-c, select, asp.net-web-api, count, odata

I want to have some query like this

```
https://localhost:44300/odata/Users?$expand=Comments&$select=Name,LastName,$count(Comments)
```

in odata. I mean that I have comments of users, and I want to return that count with user name. How can I do that?

Edit: Sample
[image: Sample Result]

Comment: Have you tried using $inlinecount=allpages?

Comment: I tried but it returns the how many result does odata returns. I want something different.Edited question with a sample.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
https://localhost:44300/odata/Users?$expand=Comments($count=true) & $select=Name,LastName
```

Comment: sorry, didnt work. "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Term 'Comments($count=true)' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression."

Comment: @kocakmstf Would you try request http://services.odata.org/v4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Trips($count=true)? The $expand can have $count option while the $select can't according to OData V4 ABNF: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt. So this isn't exactly what you want but it can give the comments count inline in the users payload.

Comment: ok, sorry i was using odata v3. v4 doesn't have datetime object and identityuser fails when i use odata v4. Because of that i couldn't upgrade version. This 'count' looks like working fine with odata v4.

Answer (score -1):

https://localhost:44300/odata/Users?$expand=Comments/$count & $select=Name,LastName

Comment: Can you explain your answer?